# Counter in For Loop of XSLT

Tags: xslt, counter

I am declaring a variable globally and want to increment in for loop with IF conditions. Then later want use that variable outside in the Trailer record of XSLT at the end.

<xsl:variable name="BENCountV">0</xsl:variable>  - Declared Globally

```
<xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:if test="../xyz">
    <WorkerBen>

    <I need to increment a variable BENCountV here once above condition is met>
                    
   </WorkerBEN>
 </xsl:if>                      
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing input and expected output.

Comment: in xslt, there's no need for a for loop to accomplish that: You would just set the variable like `<xsl:variable name="BENCountV" select="count(yourXpath[yourCondition])"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Bind a variable to the selected items:

```
<xsl:variable name="items" select="xxx[../xyz]"/>
```

Iterate over them:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$items">...</xsl:for-each>
```

Then count them:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count($items)"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I want to count based the on the IF condition inside the loop and then use that value outside of loop.

Comment: If you show us the input and the desired output then we can show you the right way to do it, which is quite different from how you would do it in a procedural language. You're thinking too procedurally.